# How to add route to custom controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes

How do I add a route to a custom controller methods in Rails?

I have the following methods and want to call them via AJAX.

```
def w_destroy
    render json: RHoliday.where(holiday_id: params[:holiday_id].to_s, group_id: params[:group_id].to_s).destroy 
end
  def w_create

        @r_holiday = RHoliday.new(r_holiday_params)

        respond_to do |format|
       if @r_holiday.save
         format.html { redirect_to @r_holiday, notice: 'RHoliday was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @r_holiday }
       else
         format.html { render action: 'new' }              format.json { render json: @r_holiday.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end
```

The question is:
How do I do this? I think I need to edit my routes.rb but I don't know what to add there. I just used `resources :r_holidays`, but this just creates the default routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [add extra routes out of resources scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) in many different ways:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :r_holidays do
    post :w_create
    delete :w_delete
end
```

Specifically, the `resources` call basically gives you Rails' standard 7 RESTful routes - you can use a code block to define extra routes as required. You should [read the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) to get some more ideas

Comment: Not a problem! Now send me some Unicoins!!

Comment: lol it's the april fool's joke on SO - check the top-right of the site ;)

Comment: Ahh... Hillarious... Thaught it's some sort of dogecoin-fake :D
How do I send them?

Comment: I think you have to find a rainbow, download the unicoins app from the iTunes store & send me some of the coins the leprechaun will give you :)

Comment: Oh... That's sad! I'm androidian :D